# Keys in React when mapping VS when normal components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why in following code:

```
<ul>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>def</li>   // works fine
</ul>
```

we do not need `key` and React will not throw any warnings and everything will work smoothly.

#### BUT

In following example:

```
<ul>
  {['abc', 'def'].map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}  // throws warning if no key
</ul>
```

WE DO need `key`, otherwise React will throw warnings.

**What is the difference** between mapped `li` components and normal `li` components?

**Why mapped `li`** requires key? And normal `li` **does not**?

Comment: Is it react (dev mode) or is it a linter that issues the warnings?

Comment: There is no difference. It's just that when you use an array, it assumes that the value is dynamic and the list might change, so for that you should use `key`s.

Comment: The docs are usually the best place to start with such questions - https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys

Comment: @andymccullough the link you provided is not that much clear about my case, it just says why its needed. It does not describe difference between mapped and normal components.

Comment: there are no ***mapped*** components. It is just that in the first case you render just the components while in the second you render an array which contains the components. You will get the same warnings if you do `<ul>{ [<li>abc</li>,<li>def</li>] }</ul>`

Answer (score 2):

When using the **map function**, you can assign a **unique key attribute** to each element. The key attribute helps React **keep track** of which elements have **changed** and **update** the **DOM** efficiently.

On the other hand, when **using a normal li tag outside of map**, it is **not necessary** to assign a **unique key attribute** because the element is not part of a dynamic list. In this case, the li element is static and will always be rendered in the **same position in the DOM**.